# AdoptOpenJDK8 can not find Openjfx package even though it is a dependency

Tags: java, javafx

I am transiting my project to use openjdk 8 from adoptopenjdk... I understand that OpenJDK does not carry javafx anymore. So I set the `org.openjfx.javafx` as my dependencies for the project. I see the dependency connected... but why does my import still can not find it?

[image]

[image]

Building in local terminal is the same issue

```
error: package javafx.util does not exist
import javafx.util.Pair;
                  ^
```

Dependences are all there...

```
compile 'org.openjfx:javafx-controls:11'
compile 'org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:11'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try to build your code outside of IntelliJ. If that works, clean the cache in Intellij and if that also doesn't help you can try to delete `.idea` directory from the project root and re-import the project. IntelliJ sadly sometimes stumbles when finding classes of already imported dependencies.

Comment: Hmm, I am building in terminal and it is the same issue - 

```error: package javafx.util does not exist
import javafx.util.Pair;
                  ^```

Comment: Can you try version 12 instead of 11? I'd might be reading wrong, but it looks like that class didn't exist in version 11.

Comment: @Tom Not trying to be critical here but out of curiosity, I was able to search up that class in my classpath in intelliJ, why is it like that?

`/Users/bthai/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.openjfx/javafx-base/11/1442a519fc1ce9ffb79adbb988e137dde2ba1219/javafx-base-11-sources.jar!/javafx/util/Pair.java`

Comment: I forget to word Github. "I'd might be reading Github wrong", because it looked like the class `Pair` were added in December 2018, but version 11 was released in September 2018. But since you can access the class correctly I really read Github wrong. Does IntelliJ allow you to successfully import a different class from the `javafx.util` package?

Comment: It's not even able to track down javafx.util in general... I would just do import and wait for it to populate... nothing comes up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve will never work because Java8 is simply not compatibel with JavaFX 11 or 12. You will either have to use a Java 8 distribution which contains JavaFX or you will have to upgrade your Java to at least 11 too.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this, after being stump on this yesterday, I gave up after 15 mins and used commons-lang Pair class instead of JavaFX :), although I was curious how did JavaFX worked with Oracle JDK8 but not OpenJDK? Is it because OracleJDK has inbuilt JavaFX?

Comment: Yes, OracleJDK contained JavaFX until and including Java 10.

Answer (score 0):

[Liberica JDK 8](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/#/java-8-lts) is an OpenJDK distribution that contains JavaFX. Choose the Full JDK.